# Оптимизированный код

Tags: c#, unity3d

Какой из написанных кодов более рациональней и правильней с точки зрения оптимизации в программировании? 1 или 2?

1.

```
public GameObject player;

private bool key;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    key = player.GetComponent<Player>().key;

    if (key == true)
    {
        player.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);

        key = false;
    }
}
```

2. 

```
public Player player;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (player.key == true)
    {
        player.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);

        player.key = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пока по замерам всё работает как надо - оба способа будут иметь право на жизнь

Comment: Без разницы. Я бы только GetComponent унес в какой-нибудь Start, если player один и тот же. Еще вот эти `== true` не нравятся, но они ни на что не влияют, компилятор их должен нормально оптимизировать.

Comment: @aepot "Я бы только GetComponent унес в какой-нибудь Start, если player один и тот же"  --- думаю именно в этом и вопрос у ТС и сложные острые муки выбора))

Comment: Непонятно, где во втором коде инициализируется `player`. И да, если `player` один, то имеет смысл его получить в `Start` и дальше обращаться к нему. И не плодить лишние глобальные переменные, если нужное поле есть в `Player`.

Comment: С точки зрения именования булевых переменных, должно быть не "key", а "hasKey". И в условии не нужно писать "if (hasKey == true)" - это избыточно, достаточно "if (hasKey)"

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin тогда уж не `hasKey`, а `playerHasKey` (точнее **object**HasKey), если это просто отдельная переменная. Но `hasKey`, если это свойство класса, например `Player`

Comment: @CrazyElf , а во втором коде: код public Player player не является заменой кода public GameObject player; вместе с инициализацией в Start() GetComponent<Player>()?

Comment: @SpaceMaks Хм, ну я юнити не настолько хорошо знаю, мне казалось, что так объекты только описывают, а инициализировать нужно отдельно как-то ещё. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: @CrazyElf , ну да. Наверное, тогда лучше вот так и сделать с инициализацией: public GameObject player; private Player playerScript; и в Strart() сделать так playerScript = player.GetComponent<Player>(); а потом уже в самом скрипте использовать: playerScript.key = .... Спасибо)